# How to post on Facebook wall using FacebookApi with user's text by choice on ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

I was searching for tutorial how to post on facebook wall some text by user's choice. Here is my login.html.erb file

```
<p>
  <%= form_for :koala,url: auth_facebook_callback_path,method: :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field @message %> <br />
    <%= f.submit "Post!" %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

This is my user.rb model

```
def self.koala(auth)
    access_token = auth['token']
    facebook = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
    facebook.get_object("me?fields=name,picture")
    facebook.put_wall_post(["#{@message}"])
  end
```

Comment: What's the error/issue?

Comment: type: FacebookApiException, code: 100, error_subcode: 1349125, message: Invalid parameter [HTTP 500]

Comment: Try `facebook.put_wall_post(@message)`. One message at a time, instead of an array of msgs

Comment: I get the same error again

Comment: have you tried this? `facebook.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")`

Comment: Yes I have but I want the user to define his own post.

Comment: Please check the value of `@messege` variable.
You can replace `:message => "I am writing on my wall!"` with `:message => "#{@message}"`

Comment: please post your controller code of `auth_facebook_callback` method

Comment: This is my routes.rb file     Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  get 'auth/facebook/callback', to: 'users#login'
  post 'auth/facebook/callback', to: 'users#login'
end